# How do I set group permissions on a shared folder?

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I have created a folder called `shared1` which I am going to share. After that, I have created a group named `group`.

Currently no users are added into `group` group.

I need to assign read and write permissions to folder `shared1` with only the `group` group having access.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what you do

Open terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type

```
sudo chmod g+rw (folder path)
```

Where folder path is the full path of the folder. ex: home/user/folder.
This basically gives (+) the group (g) read and write (rw) permission to the folder. Now type

```
sudo chmod uo-rwx (folder path)
```

this removes (-) read, write, and excecute (rwx) permissions from the owner (u [stands for user]), and others (o).

**Note:** you will need to type in your password. this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

The short command to achieve that DeveloperNewb suggests is

```
sudo chmod 060 shared1
```

But I suggest you to set permissions either to `660` or to `770` due to conveniency reasons. Once you set those permissions to `060` you have always to use `sudo` to access that folder.